# You don't have permission to access /send.php on this server

Tags: php

I have a contact form which sends to a php file on the root of my server to send an email, however I receive the following error message:

403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /send.php on this server.

The php file has 755 file permissions. I tried deleting Deny from all from the .htaccess file in the logs folder too but didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you move the php file to the public folder?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is in the public folder (e.g., /public_html/). You can't go below that level.

Also, the `.htaccess` file in the logs folder is only relevant if your script is in that folder. Based on the name "logs", you probably do want to `Deny all`. If there is an `.htaccess` file in the folder where `/send.php` is, then you may need to adjust the settings in that file.

Comment: hi, yes the php is on the same level of the htmls at the root.